# Coldfusion Charting Multiple Series from QoQ

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop, cfchart

I am trying to insert a chart in an email that will graph multiple series' data over time. The email works fine, the chart attaches successfully but something is wrong with how I am generating the chart.

**What I am attempting to do:** Loop through the query results, group by the 'territory description' (to make a series for each territory), then generate a data point for each territory for each month.

Here is a sample of the Query of Queries results that I am attempting to graph:

[image: query of queries results]

There is an entry for each of six 'territories' for each of six months.

Here is the code I found online that I've been trying to work with.

```
 <cfchart
        format="png"
        name="marketADH"
        xAxisTitle="Month"
        yAxisTitle="% Adherence"
        chartHeight = "500"    
        chartWidth = "500" 
        scalefrom="60"
        scaleto="90"
        font="Arial"
        gridlines="10"
        showXGridlines="no"
        showYGridlines="no"
        showborder="no"
        show3d="no" 
        showlegend="yes"
        sortxaxis="no"
        showmarkers="yes" 
 > 



 <cfloop query="HISTORY_CHART" group="TERRITORY_DESC"> 
      <!---- this part of the code will run ONCE for each territory ---->

   <cfchartseries 
     type="curve"
     paintStyle="plain"
     seriesLabel="#HISTORY_CHART.TERRITORY_DESC#">

     <cfloop>
         <!----- this part of the code will run once for every record for the territory  ------>
         <cfchartdata item="#HISTORY_CHART.RPT_MTH#" value="#HISTORY_CHART.ADHERENCE_PCT#">
     </cfloop>

   </cfchartseries>

  </cfloop>

 </cfchart>
```

**Results:** The chart is generating and attaching in the email, but there is only one month value - 12/01/2017 which is the first of the six months in the data set. All 36 or so values appear to be populating on the y-axis for this month.

What I expected to see was something like this:

[image: Excel Mockup]

What I ended up with was this:

[image: Actual Result]

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<cfloop query="HISTORY_CHART" group="TERRITORY_DESC">`

I'm guessing the "group" isn't working as expected because the query data isn't sorted correctly.

What the [cfloop documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-query.html) doesn't emphasize nearly enough is that the "group" feature requires query data be sorted **in the same order as the "group" statement(s)**. If it's sorted by a different column (say "Rpt_Mth") and cfloop is grouped by "Territory_Desc", you won't get the expected output.

[Sorted vs Unsorted example on TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/6eb55a710a41cb7af26929da2622e4ff/acf?theme=monokai)

Make sure the sql query sorts by the same column used in the *group*, "Territory_Desc". Then the chart should generate correctly.

```
<cfquery ...>
  SELECT Adherence_Pct,Rpt_Mth,Territory_Desc 
  FROM   TableName 
  ORDER BY Territory_Desc 
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This absolutely worked. I added this code to the QoQ and it worked like a charm. --> ORDER BY TERRITORY_DESC DESC, RPT_MTH ASC